# A-frame collision between two objects

Tags: javascript, html, aframe, virtual-reality, webvr

I am creating a game in A-frame (aframe.io) and I am trying to get an effect where when the camera touches an object, the camera and object are both blasted a few spaces away from each other. For example, if I run into a box, the box and I will both be blasted backward 2 spaces. I'm not sure how I can accomplish this effect, however. I've tried using the spring component in the A-frame physics system (https://github.com/n5ro/aframe-physics-system#spring) but haven't achieved any results. Am I doing something wrong with the spring component or is there an easier way to achieve this effect? Here is the code for my camera and gltf which should be blasted backward from each other when touching.

```
  <a-gltf-model
    src="https://cdn.glitch.com/6632f840-a210-4bdc-a62f-bc38e65ae48a%2Fscene%20-%202021-05-13T103029.286.glb?v=1620927093004"
    position="-3 0 -3"
    scale="0.035 0.035 0.035"
  ></a-gltf-model>

  

  <a-entity
    id="rig"
    position="17.5 50.1 0"
    movement-controls="speed: 0.2;"
    kinematic-body="enableJumps: true;"
    jump-ability="distance: 1.8;"
    networked="template:#avatar-template;attachTemplateToLocal:false;"
    spawn-in-circle="radius:1"
    tracker
    speed-change
    jump-change
  >
    <a-entity
      camera="far: 1000;"
      look-controls="pointerLockEnabled: true;"
      position="0 1.6 0"
    >
    </a-entity>
  </a-entity>
```

If know how I can achieve this effect, I would really appreciate it if you could take the time to answer, I've been working at this for a long time now and I just cant seem to get it right.

Comment: try making a component which will [apply an impulse](https://github.com/n5ro/aframe-physics-system#using-the-cannonjs-api) upon collision

Comment: The game I'm trying to create is multiplayer though, is there an example of how I could use this between two user's cameras?

Comment: Try doing it with two spheres, the only difference i can think of would be bouncing only 'myself' upon hitting someone

Comment: I tried the code in the repo along with the script src for cannon.js and the physics system and the code wasn't running properly. Is there a demo of this anywhere so I can see what I'm doing wrong?